# React.js Form input onChange having issue with getDerivedStateFromProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Input `onChange` not updating the state when `getDerivedStateFromProps` used. After I passed the props from parent to child, I'm checking through `getDerivedStateFromProps` from child component. Full demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/011m5jwyjw

```
class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      form: {}
    };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (nextProps.user) {
      return { form: nextProps.user };
    }

    return {
      ...prevState
    };
  }

  inputHandle(e) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      form: {
        firstname: e.target.value
      }
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        type="text"
        name="firstname"
        value={this.state.form.firstname}
        onChange={e => this.inputHandle(e)}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: "Not working" is not a proper problem description. Please explain what is happening and what you expect to happen

Comment: Also, note that you probably shouldn't even use that method: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Comment: Also note: state update is always partial, not full, so no need to return `prevState`.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from React 16.4, `getDerivedStateFromProps` is called and gets the component props on every update no matter what caused it (changing the props or the state). So every time when you call `this.setState` the form values are reset by this code:

```
if (nextProps.user) { // nextProps are here on every state change
  return { form: nextProps.user };
}
```

In order to fix it, save the current user to state and reset the `form` state attribute only when the user changes.

```
this.state = {
  form: {},
  lastUser: null,
};

// ...

static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  if (nextProps.user !== prevState.lastUser) {
    return {
      form: nextProps.user,
      lastUser: nextProps.user
    };
  }

  return {};
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/9439xnoloy)

Comment: This is working as expected. Do you know how to this without `getDerivedStateFromProps` method?

Comment: @Mifas You can make the `Form` component be fully controlled and save the form state in the `List` component